How to create a 360 degree panoramic static image with Bing Streetside?
I've read the docs and can request street side images at a given lat/lon. I'm interested in creating a 360 degree panoramic static image from four images with 90 degree field of view.
Here is the API that I'm using (with Python formatting):
https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Imagery/Map/Streetside/{lat:.6f},{lon:.6f}?fov={fov}&heading={heading:.2f}&pitch={pitch:.2f}&mapsize={size},{size}&key={key}

Here is an example panoramic image:

Notice the shearing going on between frames, and contrast this to what the tiles API produces:

The two panoramic images are roughly aligned because I've used the heading metadata of this location to request the same "front" tile image, with 90 degree offsets for the remaining left, right, and back images.
I'm not interested in the tiles API because I want to be able to specify the returned image resolution, which the first API allows. However the shearing produced by the first API is unacceptable for my application.
Does anyone know whats going on, and how I can create a 360 degree panoramic image using the first API?

The Bing streetside imagery is formatted as a cube-map. This is a standard graphics technique used to render background scenes that's more efficient than a simple cylindrical projection commonly used for panoramas. If you render the 6 faces of the cube using any 3D API around a virtual camera, you'll get an undistorted image. The images you have above are the thumbnail image which just has a tiny version of 4 faces of the cube concatenated together. The API documentation describes how to request the actual tiles for each face of the cube (the lowest level of detail has 1 tile per face)

Hi Duncan, the documentation doesn't appear to show how to request higher resolution tiles. I did eventually find out by inspecting the API requests via browser dev tools, and saw you could increase the resolution of the quadkey to get say 512x512 tiles. However this increases the number of REST API calls by 4x for each level of "zoom", eg. 24 API calls to get a cube-map with 512x512 tiles. This is why I wanted to resolve the shearing issue; so I could get a 360 pano with 4 REST API calls.

Tiles are all the same resolution - each face is a standard quad-tree of tiles of constant resolution. The system is designed for the rendering use case where you zoom in on only one part of the image, so don't want to load the whole thing.

Right, each tile is 256x256, but to get a single cube side with an effective resolution of 512x512 would result in 4 billable transactions via REST Services. It looks like the Web Control API is more economical; only the creation of a session results in a billable transaction. Is there an analog of session creation for arbitrary applications/runtimes? In my case, I do want to load the whole thing, but would prefer not to get hit with 24 or even 96 API calls

There should be only one billable transaction to get the URL from the imagery metadata service. The individual tile transactions are not billed.

You may want to check the Bing maps TOU for your use case though. Copying the imagery or storing it locally for cases other than printing is prohibited.

Is there any online documentation that states that individual tile transactions are not billed? If that could be confirmed, then we could proceed with the tile-based approach. We have reviewed the TOU prior to the project and are in compliance. The lack of local storage is a major motivator for reducing billable transactions.

See documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/getting-started/bing-maps-dev-center-help/understanding-bing-maps-transactions. The REST call for imagery metadata to get the tile URL is listed as a billable transaction. The request for the tile(s) are not. In the TOU, check section 5, f, g, k, n, or t

I did see that "RESTImagery-Metadata" was billable, but I do not see anything that explicitly states that tile requests are not billable. Is there a row in that table that corresponds to tile requests? Regarding the TOU, we've reviewed all of section 5 and we are in compliance.

If it's not listed, it's not billable. You can verify this by looking at your report in the Bing maps portal after making tile requests - they are not logged as billable transactions.

Thanks for your help, Duncan. I'll verify this via the portal. Some suggestions: (1)  non-billable tile requests should be explicit in the transactions documentation, as poor assumptions can sometimes be costly, and (2) the streetside tile tutorial should mention how one can zoom in using quadkeys, as currently there is no mention of how to utilize the zoom range metadata. If you'd like to answer this question, e.g. saying the tiles API is doesn't cause shearing and more importantly is not billable beyond a metadata request, I would mark it as correct.

The easiest option is to use the Bing Maps Web SDK as it provides that user experience out of the box and would only generate one transaction per user session. There are several code samples in the Bing Maps interactive SDK here: https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk/setviewtostreetside
Also a couple examples here: https://samples.bingmapsportal.com/?search=streetside&sample=
Note, if you only want the streetside viewer and none of the overlays (with exception the required copyright), then take a look at this sample: https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk/setdisableallstreetsideoverlays
If you want to try and build a custom control you can take a look at this open source project, but this is not a simple task: https://github.com/Microsoft/MicrosoftStreetsidePlugin

Sorry, I should have specified that I'm not interested in an interactive web user experience, but a static image. Can the SDK produce a 360 degree panoramic static image?

I'm not aware of any way to get a single panoramic static image. If there is anything, it would most likely be a random open-source project.
